# How to delete a Laravel cookie so that it's gone even in the same request

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-8

In Laravel (version 8), I can set a cookie to be deleted from the browser when the page is finally sent, using this:

`cookie()->queue(cookie()->forget("choclatechip"));`

But until the response gets sent back to the browser, the rest of my code still thinks this cookie exists (because it actually does, in a sense).

Is there some way to delete this cookie from the request, so that the rest of my code thinks it is gone now already?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean during processing the current request after some line in your code, you want the rest of ur code to not see this cookie? or you mean in processing next requests?

Comment: Not the next request.  The rest of my code during this request.

Comment: If so, how do you usually set cookies in server, as I imagine, you depend on header data and using middleware or something you set it, right? May you show me that?

Comment: I set the cookie like this: cookie()->queue(cookie()->forever("choclatechip", "some value"));

Comment: I do not know why it doesn't work with you but you may try to set it again but with null value and set it with time that's already expired.